# How to prevent Sqlite unbound parameters interpreted as NULL

Tags: sqlite, data-binding

As the Sqlite docs specify, unbound parameters in prepared statements are interpreted as NULL - my question is this then:

Is there a way to have Sqlite ensure that all parameters have been bound at least once, thereby ensuring none were missed by accident?

It is better to get an error and require calls to `sqlite3_bind_null(statement_, col);` then to get a subtle error because I forgot to call `sqlite3_bind_*` on the where clause of an update statement!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to differentiate unbound parameters from parameters set to NULL using the current SQLite libraries.

If you have a look at the C source code for `sqlite3_bind_null()`, you will find that it simply calls the internal SQLite function that unbinds a parameter. Therefore there is no way to tell the two cases apart.

The only solution for this would be to wrap the SQLite C API functions with your own functions that will do a bit of book-keeping. You can bundle a bitmap with each `sqlite3_stmt` structure, with each bit set to true if and only if the corresponding parameter is bound. You would have to create wrappers for at least the `sqlite3_bind_*()` functions and `sqlite3_clear_bindings()`.